# Adjust layout width dynamically according to size of children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a dialog layout that has a Title, Message and two buttons inside of it. I am using a Constraint layout at the moment.

I want the dialog to behave dynamically to the size of the Title, but when the Title's width is smaller than the combined width of the buttons than I want the dialog to adjust its size to the width of the Buttons. While at the same time keeping the Message displayed properly as well.

What happens now is that when the Title width is smaller than the combined width of the Buttons, the Buttons will be overlapped and the Message is cropped to the same size as the title.

This is my current XML layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_title_background"
tools:ignore="SmallSp">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/background_gradient"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_message_dialog_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_light"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_interactive_theme1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/background_gradient"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_light"
    android:textColor="@color/dialog_body_text_color"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background_gradient"/>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="37dp"
    android:paddingEnd="37dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_light"
        android:paddingStart="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="13dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_light"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="13dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button1" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have added two examples to explain my problem more clearly.

[Dialog with long title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4e5V.png)

[Dialog with short title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uffw.png)

In the first example the Title width is longer than the combined width of the Buttons, if this is the case the layout should adjust its size to the width of the Title and Button 2 should align its end with the end of the title.

In the second example the title is shorter than the combined width of the Buttons, if this is the case the layout should adjust its size to the width of the 2 Buttons.

In both cases the Message can also be a long string but it can be cut of but should be displayed properly. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your title is sometimes smaller and sometimes bigger than your combined buttons, you have a barrier probleme for your constraints. You must add a barrier and constraint your layout to the barrier, here is the documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier

Comment: In your code, becareful with android:layout_width="0dp", you should conciderate to use android:layout_width="wrap_content" for your message textview too

Comment: @Z3nk Thanks for your response i will look in to this.

Comment: Are you want to make it like those examples (`Images`)?

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Solved using **Chains** feature available in `ConstraintLayout`

> Find full documentation here : [Control linear groups with a chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)

Here's your answer

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#efefef"
    tools:ignore="SmallSp">

<View
        android:id="@+id/background_gradient"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:background="#a1a1a1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        android:textColor="#F44336"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:text="Title Text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/background_gradient"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="Message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background_gradient" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingStart="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="13dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingStart="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="13dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using chains, however this doesn't solve my problem. I have given your example a try but both the Title and Message are not displayed correctly.